# Keeping update changes for each column

Tags: sql-server, database

I've been asked by my client to manage update history for each column/field in one of our SQL Server tables. I've managed "batch" versions of entire rows before, but haven't done this type of backup/history before. They want to be able to keep track of changes for each column/field in a row of a table. I could use some help in the most efficient way to track this. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the level of change and amount of history, but the basic solution is to create a text field on the table, which is displayed to user, but not editable, where you can "annotate" the changes to the record simply using text. ie 25th July - Simo updated comment from foo to bar. 24th July - Andy updates comment from bar to foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is triggers and history tables, but the best practice depends on what data your database holds and how often and by how much it is modified.

Essentially every time a record in a table is updated, an update trigger (attached to the table) gets notified what the old record looked like and what the new record will look like.  You can then write the change history to new records to another table (i.e. tblSomething_History). Note: if updates to your tables are done via stored procs, you *could* write the history from there, but the problem with this is if another stored procedure updates your table as well, then the history won't be written.

Depending on the amount of fields / tables you want history for, you may do as suggested by @M.Al, you may embedded your history directly into the base table through versioning, or you may create a history table for each individual table, or you may create a generic history table such as:

```
| TblName | FieldName | NewValue | OldValue | User | Date Time |
```

Getting the modified time is easy, but it depends on security setup to determine which user changed what. Keeping the history in a separate table means less impact on retrieving the current data, as it is already separated you do not need to filter it out.  But if you need to show history most of the time, this probably won't has the same effect.

Unfortunately you cannot add a single trigger to all tables in a database, you need to create a separate trigger for each, but they can then call a single stored procedure to do the guts of the actual work.

Another word of warning as well: automatically loading all history associated with tables can dramatically increase the load required, depending on the type of data stored in your tables, the history may become systematically larger than the base table.  I have encountered and been affected by numerous applications that have become unusable, because the history tables were needlessly loaded when the base table was, and given the change history for the table could run into 100's per item, that's how much the load time increased.

Final Note: This is a strategy which is easy to absorb if built into your application from the ground up, but be careful bolting it on to an existing solution, as it can have a dramatic impact on performance if not tailored to your requirements.  And can cost more than the client would expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on a similar database not long ago, where no row is ever deleted, every time a record was updated it actually added a new row and assigned it a version number. something like....

Each table will have two columns

```
Original_ID |  Version_ID
```

each time a new record is added it gets assigned a sequential `Version_ID` which is a Unique Column and the `Original_ID` column remains NULL, On every subsequent changes to this row will actually insert a new row into the table and increases the Version_ID and the Version_ID that was assigned when the record was 1st created will be assigned to `Original_ID`.

If you have some situations where records need deleting, use a BIT column `Deleted` and set its value to `1` when a records is suppose to be deleted, Its called (Soft Deletion).

Also add a column something like `LastUpdate` datetime, to keep track of time that a change was made.

This way you will end up with all versions of a row starting from where a row is inserted till its is deleted (Soft deletion).

Comment: I see how this would work when a row is updated. But how do I keep track of when each column in the row is updated and the version history of each column? Not just the row?

Comment: No row is ever updated, once a row is inserted you assign a version to it and if you want to "UPDATE" that row you will insert a new row with same Original_ID but a newer Version_ID. This way you will end up with all the versions of a row in your table. Read me answer again, please dont make me explain here what I already have in my answer.

Comment: I completely understand your answer. But I need a version history for each field/column. When I present data to client and let's say they "updated" the last name field only on Jan 15. I need to be able to bold that last name field and say that it was recently "updated". They need a version history for each column/field.