# SQL Server Capturing Data at a point in time

Tags: sql, sql-server, schedule

I have a requirement to capture data at a point in time from a certain table, I'll call this table Orders.

As a solution to this problem, I have created a new table, I'll call this OrdersCaptured, and have a stored procedure to periodically insert records into this new table OrdersCapture to capture the data I require.

This way, if any records get deleted or update in the Orders table, if we run a report on the OrdersCapture table, it will show what orders were there for that point in time.

The OrdersCapture table will hold a date field for when the stored procedure was run to capture the data and I can query this table on that date field to see what the data looked like within that date range.

The reason I am doing this is to track the backlog of orders at a point in time.

However, I was wondering whether there is an alternative way to do this in SQL Server. I will need to support SQL Server 2005 upwards.

Any feedback on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: I would go for a trigger on that Orders tables and insert everyrecord on the OrdersCaptured as if it was an audit table.

Comment: Or don't allow updates on the `orders`table and add a `version` column.

Comment: It really shouldn't be possible to delete an order from an orders table. Consider having a status of 'Cancelled' in a column like ORDER_STATUS. And ORDER_EFFDT to track changes to orders over time. (with respect to what the application inserts into it)

Comment: I answered to a similar question a couple of days ago have a look here [`Keeping update changes for each column`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922892/keeping-update-changes-for-each-column/24923031#24923031)

Comment: If the application code can be easily modified, you can add a DELETED_DATE column to the Orders table. Then, you can easily determine which records were "active" at a given point of time (either `DELETED_DATE IS NULL or DELETED_DATE > reporting_date`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, however, I don't think anything mentioned in the comments will work as an alternative to what I've already done which is working fine. I will edit my post to maybe make it abit more clear.